# FileNotFound exception for the existing file in the Azure Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, file-not-found

I'm trying to generate a file to be downloaded by user. 
Here is my code to create a temp folder:

```
tempPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "Temp");
if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
}
```

The Directory.Exists returns false even if the directory is there (I've checked that in Kudu). Then the Directory.CreateDirectory fails with an error:

```
Could not find file 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\wwwroot\\Temp
```

What could be the root cause? It works fine on the local machine.

Comment: \\wwwroot\\wwwroot is right?

Comment: Yes, the directory should be created in wwwroot dir

Comment: wwwroot dir inside wwwroot?

Comment: yes, the site assemblies are being deployed inside D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot. The static content then goes to D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\wwwroot

Comment: okay, then nvm. I thought that this could be the issue.

Comment: @NikitaFedorov For testing purpose, can you just hardcode the path in your code?

Comment: @IvanYang already did it. The same result. I even removed this part and created directory manually, but then the creation of the files for users also is failing with the same error.

Comment: How are you doing the deployment? If you are using something like Azure DevOps the deployment settings may also be useful if you could share them. Getting a "File not Found" when it is there usually means a permissions issue in Core. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26561

Answer (score 0):

First, reference [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) to ensure the file existed.

Refer to this article, this is an Azure App service [issue](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/80283-app_plugins-path-error-on-azure-web-apps). Add `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0`in Application Setting then it will work fine.

[image]